# Find earliest object that has no children - Django

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship, django-queryset

What I am trying to do is to find the earliest `article` that has no related `article_history`.

Here is what I tried, but isn't working:

```
the_article = Article.objects.filter(cowcode=country).filter(pubdate__range=(start_date,end_date)).exclude(article_history_set__id > 0).order_by('pubdate')[0]
```

My thinking behind this was that the query is working until the exclude: I get all the articles that match the condition. Since I want to find the earliest article that has no `article history` attached yet, `exclude`ing all articles that have articles with an article_history id > 0 should work. Why isn't it?

Would be awesome if someone could help me out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
...end_date)).filter(article_history_set__isnull=True).order_by...
```

or

```
...end_date)).exclude(article_history_set__isnull=False).order_by…
```

---

and if you have self-relational foreign key as parent-children you can do that:

```
....filter(children__isnull=True).order_by...
```

or

```
....exclude(children__isnull=False).order_by...
```

Comment: Yes, I only had to add "=False" to it, so it looked like this:
`)).exclude(article_history_set__isnull=False).order_by…`